# How to add addons to remote webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

capabilities = {
     "browserName": "firefox"}

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension('/Users/cookie_manager.xpi')

driver = Remote(browser_profile=profile,
     command_executor="http://url.com:4444/wd/hub",
     desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

DeprecationWarning: Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile

How do you use FirefoxOptions? I cannot find documentation for options adding addons.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following you, but there's [`install_addon`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html), which is for Firefox specifically.

Comment: @orde Install addon can't be used with the selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver (Remote class) only the selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver firefox class. I am connecting to a remote selenium container running on a different host, but I can't figure out how to install an addon on a remote selenium session.